# Save a file with the option to open it

Tags: java, save, filedialog

I am looking for a solution to save a file in a Java (Eclipse RCP) application with the option to open the file right after saving it. Similar is when a browser saves a dowloaded file it allowes to open it. A simple FileDialog has no such option.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to open the file yourself after you save it.

Do the following (in windows):

```
String cmd = "cmd.exe /c start ";
String file = "path\version.txt"; //TODO: your file path here
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd + file);
```

Similar approach can be applied for linux environment. Search for it yourself.

If you need the option (may be a checkbox) in JFileChooser, you can extend JFileChooser and add your features.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such solution already implemented. But you can still search on google for it.